# React Performance: What is a good strategy to maintain constant references for event handler props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assuming I have a slow component, it makes sense to memoize it, e.g.

```
const SlowButton = ({onClick}) => {
    // make some heat
    const value = (function f(n) { return n < 2 ? Math.random() : f(n-1) + f(n-2)})(32)|0;
    return <button onClick={() => onClick(value)}>{value}</button>
}
const MemoButton = React.memo(SlowButton);
```

If I use the MemoButton in a component like:

```
const Counter = () => {
    const [clicks, setClicks ] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setClicks(clicks + 1);
    }
    return <div>
            <div>{clicks}</div>
            <MemoButton onClick={handleClick} />
        </div>
}
```

Then the MemoButton still re-renders every time because the `onClick` property is a new function every render.  It is pretty easy to resolve this with:

```
const Counter2 = () => {
    const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        setClicks(c => c + 1);
    },[]);

    return <div>
            <div>{clicks}</div>
            <MemoButton onClick={handleClick} />
        </div>
}
```

The above works fine, but with a more complicated component, it doesn't work so well:

```
const CounterGroup = () => {
    const numButtons = 3;
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('button X clicked');
    const handleClick = (val, idx) => setMessage(`button ${idx} clicked: ${val}`);
    return <div>
        <div>{message}</div>
        {Array(numButtons).fill(0).map((_, i) => 
            <MemoButton key={i} onClick={(v) => handleClick(v,i)} />)
        }
        </div>
}
```

In the above code, `(v) => handleClick(i,v)` is always going to be a new function reference.  *Is there a good technique to keep this from changing every render?*

One possibility is to just ignore changes to 'on...' props, but this just creates new problems:

```
const compareValuePropsOnly = (prev, next) => Object.entries(prev).every(
    ([k, v]) => k.substr(0, 2) === "on" || v === next[k]
);
const MemoOnlyValsButton = React.memo(SlowButton, compareValuePropsOnly);
```

Here is a codesandbox version: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/memoization-function-reference-changes-9c1fy

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to let your `SlowButton` pass the `i` value, instead of getting it from the loop, and memoize `handleClick`

```js
const SlowButton = ({onClick, i}) => {
    // make some heat
    const value = (function f(n) { return n < 2 ? Math.random() : f(n-1) + f(n-2)})(32)|0;
    return <button onClick={() => onClick(value, i)}>{value}</button>
}
const MemoButton = React.memo(SlowButton);

const CounterGroup = () => {
    const numButtons = 3;
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('button X clicked');
    const handleClick = React.useCallback((val, idx) => setMessage(`button ${idx} clicked: ${val}`), []);
    return <div>
        <div>{message}</div>
        {Array(numButtons).fill(0).map((_, i) => 
            <MemoButton key={i} i={i} onClick={handleClick} />)
        }
        </div>
}
```

Another way is to exclude 'onClick' props in your `React.memo` (since it's an event handler, it shouldn't impact how the component looks like).

```js
  const MemoButton = React.memo(SlowButton, (props1, props2) => {
    // assume that SlowButton have some props that affect it's UI
    // we don't compare onClick because it won't affect UI
    return props1.someUIProps === props2.someUIProps;
})
```

Or you can use the `useEventCallback` hook to memo your function. In this case, you need to make a component between `CounterGroup` and `MemoButton`

```
const useEventCallback = (callback) => {
  // store latest callback
  const ref = useRef(callback);
  useEffect(() => ref.current = callback);

  // memoize the callback to maintain its identity
  return useCallback((...args) => ref.current(...args), []);
}
const FastButton = ({onClick} => {
 // FastButton will be re-rendered multiple times, but since memoOnClick have same identity
 // on sub sequence re-renders, MemoButton should not be re-rendered
 const memoOnClick = useEventCallback(onClick);

 return <MemoButton onClick={memoOnClick} />
});


const CounterGroup = () => {
    const numButtons = 3;
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('button X clicked');
    const handleClick = (val, idx) => setMessage(`button ${idx} clicked: ${val}`);
    return <div>
        <div>{message}</div>
        {Array(numButtons).fill(0).map((_, i) => 
            <FastButton key={i} onClick={(v) => handleClick(v,i)} />)
        }
        </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the value that should be memoized is the function/its result, not the component. At least in your example, there is nothing specific to the component that is passed into that expensive function. Even if it did accept values from the prop, you could still memoize that function based on the values specific to it, rather than have it re-evaluated for every other prop change.

```
const SlowButton = ({onClick}) => {
  // make some heat
  const value = useMemo(
    () => (function f(n) { return n < 2 ? Math.random() : f(n-1) + f(n-2)})(32)||0,
    []
  );

  return <button onClick={() => onClick(value)}>{value}</button>
}
```